# Understanding of the promises chaining: 'then()' get's undefined parameter as the result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I started to work deeply with promises, and need your help to understand why this code doesn't work as expected.

---

Here is what I need:

After successful profile retrieving the code should log out ('success getting Profile!') which it does, and return `true` as result, that should be passed to the next `then()` element. But instead of `true`, I get `undefined` as the result.

```
  public verifyAuth(): angular.IPromise<boolean> {
    let promise: ng.IPromise<boolean> = this._Token.getIdToken()
      .then((idToken) => {
        if (!idToken) {
          return false;
        }
        else if (this._Profile.isEmpty()) {
          promise = this.retrieveProfileInfo()
            .then(() => {
              this._$log.log('success getting Profile!');
              return true;
            });
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this._Token.clearToken();
        this._$log.error(error);
        return false;
      });

    return promise;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the first `promise` object before your reassign it later in the success `then` block. You don't need to do it just use chaining like this:

```
public verifyAuth(): angular.IPromise<boolean> {
  let promise: ng.IPromise<boolean> = this._Token.getIdToken()
    .then((idToken) => {
      if (!idToken) {
        return false;
      }
      else if (this._Profile.isEmpty()) {
        return this.retrieveProfileInfo()
          .then(() => {
            this._$log.log('success getting Profile!');
            return true;
          });
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this._Token.clearToken();
      this._$log.error(error);
      return false;
    });

  return promise;
}
```

Note, how you simply `return this.retrieveProfileInfo()` which becomes new `promise` automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response!